# What is TimeHash and How it Works?

Tags: time, hash

I am doing my rapport of a final year project.
I have used [**time-hash**](https://github.com/abeusher/timehash) algorithm in my project, unlike geo-hash, i didn't find a clear explanation about time-hash and how that works ?

Comment: Please provide some context in which this term is used.

Comment: i used it to hash time , as the geohash algorithm used to hash (latitude,longitude)

Comment: So you used something you don't understand? How did you prove that it works as expected when you don't know what to expect?

Comment: what i know is that it s used for searching  time intervals like geohash is used to search location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my github.com project timehash:

timehash is an algorithm (with multiple reference implementations) for calculating variable precision sliding windows of time. When performing aggregations and correlations on large-scale data sets, the ability to convert precise time values into 'malleable intervals' allows for many novel analytics.

Using sliding windows of time is a common practice in data analysis but prior to the timehash algorithm it was more of an art than a science.

- convert epoch miliseconds into an interval of time, depicted by an ASCII character 'hash' (a 'timehash')
- timehash values are well suited to referencing time intervals in
  key-value stores (e.g. Hbase, Acculumo, Redis)
- The creation of a compound key of space and time (e.g.
  geohash_timehash) is a powerful primitive for understanding
  geotemporal patterns

[image: timehash image]

https://github.com/abeusher/timehash